# Problems with epstopdf: using .tif files in Latex does not work

Tags: graphics, epstopdf

I am writing my thesis in Latex and have multiple `.tif` pictures to include. Of course, I can convert them manually, but I would prefer to let Latex do this job to save time.

I am trying to use the `epstopdf` package for converting the `.tif` files and included the following code in the preamble of my `.tex` document:

```
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{convert #1 \OutputFile}
\AppendGraphicsExtensions{.tif}
```

However, this does not work, I get an error for the line of the `.tif` file in the log as follows:

```
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <picture.tif>
(epstopdf) date: 2015-08-18 14:06:10
(epstopdf) size: 1231850 bytes
(epstopdf) Output file: <picture-tif-converted-to.png>
(epstopdf) Command: <convert picture.tif picture-tif-converted-to.png>
(epstopdf) \includegraphics on input line 331.
runsystem(convert picture.tif picture-tif-converted-to.png)...executed.
Package epstopdf Info: Result file: <picture.png>.
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `picture.png' not found.
```

For your information, I changed the file name to keep the code a bit more simple. But this should not matter to the issue.

In addition, Texmaker tells me the following:

```
Process started
Invalid Parameter - picture-tif-converted-to.png
Process exited with error(s)
```

---

I have also tried the following commands instead of the regular one from above. I found them in a forum where this answer was accepted and seemed to work:

```
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `basename #1 .tif`.png}
\AppendGraphicsExtensions{.tif}
```

or respectively this command for the same picture in the subfolder "figures":

```
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .tif`.png}
\AppendGraphicsExtensions{.tif}
```

Both commands produce the same error in Texmaker and the log file as with the regular command above.

---

I have also tried an alternative with the following code in my preamble:

```
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\def\eattif#1.tif{#1}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{ `convert #1 \eattif#1-tif-converted-to.png }
\AppendGraphicsExtensions{.tif}
```

Nevertheless, this code does not even get to the converting of the picture, but produces another error, namely that there is one `}` too much in the third line. And I can't figure out where this should be.

---

Since I am running Miktex, I have also enabled the shell extension (for all of the alternatives posted above) by using pdflatex in Texmaker as follows:

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape --enable-write18 %.tex
```

I am running out of ideas now about how to make it work. It seems to me that the `epstopdf` package is successfully called, but there is no output file in the folder where the picture and the `.tex` file is saved, neither is it somewhere else on my computer.

I am using the `graphicx` package to include my pictures.

---

Maybe one of you guys knows more??

Is it possible that the epstopdf package conflicts with another package??

---

OS: Win 7 Enterprise 64bit

Latex: Basic Miktex 2.9.5640 (update of all packages was run today)

Editor: Texmaker 4.4.1

Comment: To convert a ton of images from one format to another on Windows, I normally end up using [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com). Batch conversion instructions can be found [here](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/50519/simple-batch-conversion-using-irfanview/), among other places. This doesn't answer your specific question, but you end up with the same result: a bunch of PNG files from your TIFF originals.

Comment: @MikeRenfro: Thanks for your comment and the link to the instructions for the batch processing with [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/). I am aware of this method and thinking about using it, before I spend too much time on fixing my Latex issue. Still, I hope your hint can be useful for other people. Additionally, I am still interested in my issue and also wanted to summarize different pieces of code regarding the `epstopdf` package.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone stumbling over this like me after having this problem as well:
After installing ImageMagick (which is needed for the convert) and restarting TexStudio in my case the first version with epstopdf worked perfectly.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!